# AvalonEdit default color when no rules are matched?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, avalonedit

Currently when there is text with no rules matched, the text defaults to be black. I've tried to change the highlight color of the default text, but so far no luck.

Any suggestions on how I could go about updating the default text color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the default text color in the syntax highlighting. Instead, just set `editor.Foreground`.

Comment: gosh! almost 10y and still no better solution?!? this, of course, works, but how unpractical it is, to have to define colors in two places!